# Does the semi-stable set determine the linearization of a GIT quotient?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups, line-bundles, group-actions

Suppose I have a morphism $f:X\to Y$ which is a GIT quotient of $X$ with respect to some reductive, linear group. 
Does the semistable $X^{ss}$ and stable locus $X^s\subset X$ determine completely the linearization (maybe up to taking a power of the linearization itself)?

Or, in better words, can two different linearizations $L$ and $L'$ of different GIT quotients of $X$ give the same semi-stable and stable locus?

Comment: I think I have found an example that shows that the answer is YES. Two differente linearizations may give the same (semi-)stable locuses. I would be glad if someone could prove me wrong, though!

Comment: Let $X = ({\mathbb P}^1)^2$, $Y = pt$, $G = T^2$. 
Let ${\mathcal O}(a) \boxtimes {\mathcal O}(b)$ carry the natural action. Then for all $a,b>0$, the stable locus is the open $T^2$-orbit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The paper you want to have a look at is Thaddeus, [GIT and Flips](https://doi.org/10.1090/S0894-0347-96-00204-4) ([JSTOR](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2152810)), or Dolgachev–Hu, [Variation of GIT quotients](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF02698859) ([Numdam](http://www.numdam.org/item?id=PMIHES_1998__87__5_0)).

There are finitely many polyhedral chambers within the space of possible linearizations. In the interior of each chamber, the sets $X^s$ and $X^{ss}$ are constant. Crossing a wall, these sets change; in nice situations, the two GIT quotient $X^{ss}/G$ on each side of the wall are related by a flip.